# Cоздание файла на клиенте с помощью HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5, файлы

Стоит задача генерить файл на клиенте и выводить кнопку скачать. После скачивания файл становится не нужен. Пример создания (с хабра).

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    // fileEntry будет иметь следующие свойства
    // fileEntry.isFile === true
    // fileEntry.name == 'log.txt'
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/log.txt'

  }, errorHandler);

}
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

То есть, файл создан как `PERSISTENT` и находится по пути `/log.txt.`

Вопросы подразумевают короткие ответы, поэтому перечислю все сразу.

1. Для скачивания этого файла достаточно написать `<a href="/log.txt">Cкачать</a>`?
2. Удалится ли файл при обновлении страницы или нужно прописывать функцию удаления?
3. Если не удалится, то перезапишется ли он при следующем вызове этой функции? И может целесообразно в таком случае вызывать функцию очистки хранилища ПЕРЕД записью нового файла?

Comment: Я немного отвлеченно напишу, но... вам точно пока это очень нужно? посмотрите на поддержку браузерами: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Comment: (О_о) Честно говоря, не знал что все так плохо. Помню, что изначально только Хром поддерживал, но спустя столько времени... Ну да ладно, для общего развития все равно полезно. Просто нужна генерация именно на клиенте, сервер не резиновый. Видимо, остается писать весь файл в dataURI... Благо он небольшой.

Comment: @qtm localstorage юзайте

Comment: Я уже реализовал через Blob